# How to get automatically added rows to appear at the top of Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new at this, so please bear with me.

I have a Google Sheet that uses a script to pull the body text of certain emails into Google Sheets.  I then use the 'left' and 'right' functions in Sheets to break the text down into useful bite size pieces.  I then have that useful information displayed on the first page of the Sheet so that I can see who sent the email, their phone number, what they want, etc.  All of that works fine, but when I get a new email it adds the information to the bottom of the sheet, and I'd very much like new information to be added at the top(but still below my headers - row 2).

I can put up an example, or even give access to the Sheet if that would help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LABEL");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      if (messages[j].isUnread())
          {
            var msg = messages[j].getBody();      
            sheet.appendRow([msg]);
            messages[j].markRead();
          }
    }
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

If I'm honest I don't understand everything this is doing, but I've cobbled it together from other answers here and it seems to do what I want, so I'm going with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said: `I have a Google Sheet that uses a script to pull the body text of certain emails into Google Sheets.`

So that script should insert a new row where ever you want it and the copy that information into that new row.

You said: `it gets added with appendRow`

So take the parameter of `appendRow(parameter)` and stick into the following function as the rowArray.  Also provide the rownumber where you want it to go, the sheetname, and the spreadsheet object.

```
function insertRowAndCopyDataIntoIt(rownumber,rowArray,sheetname,spreadsheet) {
  var ss=spreadsheet;
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  sh.insertRowBefore(rownumber);
  sh.getRange(rownumber,1,1,rowArray.length).setValues([rowArray]);  
}
```

As an alternative you could provide the current function and I'll fix it for you.

I tested this version.  It doesn't do it line by line.  Instead it takes whatever is already there and put it's into an array and then it adds new items to  the beginning of the array with the unshift() method and does a setValues() at the end thus accomplishing the very same thing but with less i/o writes and so it's much faster.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('OB BAT Emails');
  var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("OB");
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow();
  if(lr>0) {
    var msgA=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  }else{
    var msgA=[];
  }
  var threads=label.getThreads();
  for (var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0;j<messages.length;j++) {
      if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
        var msg=messages[j].getBody();  
        msgA.unshift([msg]);
        messages[j].markRead();
      }
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,msgA.length,msgA[0].length).setValues(msgA);
}
```

This function first looks to see if there is any data on the sheet.  If there is then all of the message are placed into msgA.  As the script finds more message that meet your criteria then they are added the beginning of msgA.  At the end the function replaces all of the data on the sheet with the data in msgA thus moving down the old data and leaving the most recent messages on the top.

More Columns needed ... Here's eight:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('OB BAT Emails');
  var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Q0/TEST");
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow();
  if(lr>0) {
    var msgA=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
  }else{
    var msgA=[];
  }
  var threads=label.getThreads();
  for (var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0;j<messages.length;j++) {
      if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
        var msg=['','','','','','','',''];
        msg[0]=messages[j].getPlainBody().slice(0,49999);;
        msgA.unshift(msg);
        messages[j].markRead();
      }
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,msgA.length,msgA[0].length).setValues(msgA);
}
```

Comment: I guess that's what I can't figure out.  I get the Body of the message and then it gets added with appendRow.  I don't know how to get the Body of an email, Insert a row above the current information, then add the Body in the newly created row.  I have no background in this and I'm trying to figure it out as I go.  Sorry if my description doesn't make sense.

Comment: Added edit to original with function for you to take a look at

Comment: Thank you, but the new version didn't work, and I don't know that I can describe how it's being weird.  Maybe I'll try again tomorrow morning.

Comment: I tested it last night and it works OK for me but if you’ll give me a copy of your spreadsheet I’ll test it on that. I didn’t see the remove label thing on the end of the function and I ended up removing a bunch of labels and had to write a function and put them back again so that was kind of fun.  I did change the starting row from for to two I finally read that in your question so maybe that was part of your problem

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JQcgze7RgmwhGOGoN_myGWAYRN7gnoLZcybKxGbYKhE/edit?usp=sharing  I set it to anyone can edit.  When you're done I'll switch it back to private.  Thanks for the help.  There is probably a simpler way to do what I'm attempting, but this is they way I've been able to figure out, and it works, so...

Comment: I modified it a bit.  After messing  up my emails last night I started using something like this to get them back in order and the version that you see is what I'm using to accomplish something similar.

Comment: I'm not going to pretend like I understand everything that is going on there, but it does what I want, and I can study all of it to figure it out later.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I added a brief explanation for you.  If you need more help let me know.

Comment: I've run into a snag and I'm wondering if you're willing to help out a bit more.  The information comes from my email, puts new emails on the top row, gets broken into the useful information, and then that information is displayed on the first page.  Which is all great.  Then I add notes in cells to the right.  When a new email comes in the information from the email gets moved down to make way for the new email, but my notes stay where they are.  Any idea how to get them to move down as well?

Comment: I thought that you were just using that one  column.  I'll change it.

Comment: I should explain better.  Step 1: I get an email, and the script pulls the body of it into cell A1 on sheet 2. Step 2: I copy the text of that cell into Cell A1 on sheet 3. Step 3: I use left and right functions in cells B1:M1 to get the relevant information from the email into individual cells (things like Name, Phone Number, Request, etc.) Step 4: I copy that relevant information into cells A2-F2 on sheet 1 so that I just see the information I'm interested in on the front page. Step 5: I add notes into cell G2:H2 on sheet 1 like when I called them and the result of the call. see next comment

Comment: Steps 1-5 work like a charm.  The issue arrives when I get another email.  The script moves everything down one line so that the information from the new email is on the top row, but my notes in G2:H2 stay where they are and are no longer aligned with the correct email information.  Is it possible to get those notes to move down too when a new email comes in?

Comment: I’ll take another look at it. Oh I see you added a detailed explanation I will review that carefully and get back with you thanks

Comment: So I gather that my piece of the puzzle just involves Sheet1.  And now I realize that Sheet1. Is 8 column wide.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: got: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 24, file "Code")   Also I made the sheet public, so you can take a look at it if that would be helpful.  Link in in an above comment.

Comment: We seem to be going back and forth here.  I think it would be helpful to see a copy of your current script in combination a sample spreadsheet that generates the current problem.

Comment: Sheet I am currently working on:[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JQcgze7RgmwhGOGoN_myGWAYRN7gnoLZcybKxGbYKhE/edit?usp=sharing) Script & various functions in this sheet.  Let me know if there is anything else I can provide.  Again, thank you for all the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206928/discussion-between-mschawacker-and-cooper).